# How is reverse saturation current of a BJT measured empirically?

Tags: bjt, current-measurement, saturation

I'm not asking the definition, but wondering how do the manufacturers measure this parameter's quantity in a lab for instance? For example for Ic Vce characteristics they keep Ib constant and they obtain plots. What is the procedure for obtaining  reverse saturation current of a BJT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Ies in this case is Is: Reverse Saturation Current. When they measure it, they just take several different current readings for several different Base Emitter voltages. They also do this at a "constant" temperature, or they use a cold junction reference to actively measure the temperature. Solve for the unknown. (Note: "Ies" = emitter saturation current, and this is a first order approximation) You **could** put the base-emitter into reverse bias, but you'd need to be very careful to not destroy the device as Vebo is generally around 5V or less! Where as the first technique has much more tolerance for not destroying your BJT that you might want to use.

Edit: A more precise answer due to some ambiguity of the question.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Where

- ic = collector current
- ib = base current
- ie = emitter current
- βF = forward common-emitter current gain
- βR = reverse common-emitter current gain
- Is = reverse saturation current
- Vbe = base-emitter voltage
- Vbc = base-collector voltage
- Vt = thermal voltage

Solve for as many of these as you feel like to find Is.

Comment: Are you sure?  Reverse Saturation Current flows from collector to base as far as I know. Emitter even can be open.

Comment: @user16307, BJTs are a three terminal device. That means there are **TWO** reverse saturation currents. One for the Emitter and one for the Collector. The more useful is the emitter-base reverse saturation current, as that's the one that helps you determine emitter current versus base-emitter voltage in forward active and edge of saturation (where most bjts tend to be used). I'll edit the question to have the full equations.

Comment: no in all literature Reverse Saturation Current described as which flows from collector to base as leakage. please show a reference what u claim.

Comment: You could think about it logically before asking for a source. If Is was the Reverse Saturation Current of the Base-Collector then no matter how much you increased the reverse biased voltage on the B-C junction, no more current would flow. That means that the only other source for current to the emitter would have to be the base. Thus with a reverse saturated B-C region delivering a "set in stone" current, as the emitter current rises, the base would have to provide **ALL** that increase. But that isn't the case.

Comment: @user16307, I highly doubt you've read "all literature" or you wouldn't be asking this question nor having this argument about why you think my answer is wrong.

If you still insist on a source to prove my point: Solid State Devices 6th ed. page 357 (my old college textbook for my Solid State class)

Comment: okay lets take it easy and assume im asking about  Icbo when emitter is open. is that more clear now?

Comment: @user16307, yes that is the second reverse saturation current. Yes, you must measure it as C-B reverse biased, and emitter open (that's *literally* what Icbo means "the **current** through the reverse bias **c**ollector-**b**ase junction with the emitter **o**pen"). No, you can't use that for the Ie equation I posted, but yes you can use it for an Ic equation that looks similar.

Comment: ok but im asking how they measure it? which voltage and conditions applied?

Comment: If the data sheet doesn't give you the voltage and temp used, then shame on the manufacturer. Reverse Saturation Currents (by definition) don't vary **too much** regardless of the voltage used to measure them. In practice this can actually vary by up to 10%. Most manufacturers just pick the voltage as 80% of the rated Vcbo voltage. Temperature is always at SATP (25 °C & 100 kPa) unless otherwise stated. They use a voltage source and current meter to read the data in. Passed this it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: they dont write how they measure they write results, thats why i asked this question.